# PhpStorm PestPHP ShouldNotHappen

Tags: php, phpstorm, pestphp

For some reason I always get this error when I try to run Pest tests in PhpStorm:

```
/usr/local/bin/php ~/project/vendor/pestphp/pest/bin/pest --teamcity --configuration ~/project/phpunit.xml ~/project/tests/Feature/SampleTest.php

Pest 1.20.0

   Pest\Exceptions\ShouldNotHappen 

  
This should not happen - please create an new issue here: https://github.com/pestphp/pest.

- Issue: Test file not found.
- PHP version: 8.1.0RC5-dev
- Operating system: Darwin

  at pestphp/pest/src/Exceptions/ShouldNotHappen.php:38
     34▕      * Creates a new instance of should not happen without a specific exception.
     35▕      */
     36▕     public static function fromMessage(string $message): ShouldNotHappen
     37▕     {
  ➜  38▕         return new ShouldNotHappen(new Exception($message));
     39▕     }
     40▕ }
     41▕

      +3 vendor frames 
  4   tests/Feature/SampleTest.php:38
      it("it validates the form", Object(Closure))
```

- OS: macOS Monterey (but I had the same problem in Big Sur, too)
- PhpStorm: 2021.2.2
- Pest plugin: 1.2.1 (same bug since previous versions, but not sure which one exactly)
- PHP: 8.1.0RC5-dev (same bug since 8.0)

This exact command `/usr/local/bin/php ~/project/vendor/pestphp/pest/bin/pest --teamcity --configuration ~/project/phpunit.xml ~/project/tests/Feature/SampleTest.php` works perfectly when I run it directly from the Terminal, but never from PhpStorm.

Here's my Pest plugin configuration in PhpStorm:

[image]

PS: all ~/ paths are replacing real absolute paths.
PPS: this plugin did work last year, right after the first public release of PestPHP. I wonder what went wrong (on my side, I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the reason behind this issue.

I added the parent folder as a project which holds two different repositories: "api" and "web".

As soon as I only opened the "api" project, the tests were able to run. In order to have both projects in one window I attached the other ("web") project to the already open folder.